# Detect when Fragment is fully replaced

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to android and I have a problem.
I have one main activity that is replacing fragments, I want to add custom listener for this fragments, to do that I have to get my fragment by tag.
However it gives me nullPointerException and this is because I am trying to find the fragment before it has been fully replaced.
Is there any way to get to know when fragment is fully replaced and then add my listener?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: yes you can do it using onAttached() method.

Comment: post the code of one of your fragment I will integrate the listener for you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out, and for the help. Already implementing it :)